# How come in the DRF source code for IsAuthenticated, it returns `request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()` when request.user is not a boolean?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If we look at the **DRF** source code here: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/permissions.py#L40, this is the code for `IsAuthenticated`:

```
class IsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to authenticated users.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()
```

I'm just wondering what the `return request.user` part does, because `request.user` is a user object, not a boolean. So if `request` does not have a `user` then an attribute error will be raised, correct? But if we leave out the `return request.user` part and simply have `return request.user.is_authenticated()`, then an attribute error will still be raised if `request` does not have a `user`, so what's the point of adding `return request.user` at the beginning?

Shouldn't it rather be using a `try` and `except` like this:

```
class IsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to authenticated users.
    """

def has_permission(self, request, view):
    try:
        return request.user.is_authenticated()
    except:
        # If the above raises an error (meaning user is not part of request),
        # then deny permission by returning False.
        return False
```

By using the above method, no error will be raised, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python evaluates "boolean" expression starting by left to right, if any conditions fails and transform the whole expression in `False` or `True`, python stop the evaluation and returns the value.

So if `request.user` is `None`, the whole expression is `False`, then python returns `False` and skip `request.user.is_authenticated()` evaluation. So, you won't get "attribute error" exception.

Note:
If `request` object has not `user` attribute, you will get an attribute error, but `request` object always on that step has an object or `None`. But, not always that object has `is_authenticated()` method.

This behaviour is called [short-circuit-evaluation](http://cis.poly.edu/cs1114/pyLecturettes/short-circuit-eval.html)

Also, the method is named "has_permission", so,  is better to return a `boolean` saying if the current user if exists it has permission  than raising an exception. Also, using try/except block, how are you sure that the raised exception is because `request.user` does not exists? even when you catch the correct exception, you needed at least 6 lines to representing 1.

Also in python

```
1 and 2 == True
```

Even when `1` and `2` are not `"booleans"`. So, it does not matters if `request.user` is not a "boolean", its about to check if `request.user` exists and is not `None`.

Comment: Hm, okay thanks. So just to clarify, python does not raise an attribute error if I do `return a.b` if `.b` doesn't exist? Python return False instead? Because I tried doing `print(a.b)` when `.b` does not exist and I got an attribute error.

Comment: @user2719875 Yes, it will. If `request` object has not `user` attribute, you will get an attribute error, but `request` object always at that step has a `user` object. But, not always that object has `is_authenticated()` method

Comment: @user2719875 Also, in that step, request.user may has be defined but it has None not an user object.

Comment: Right, makes sense. But shouldn't DRF do a try and except when trying to access request.user.is_authenticated() then (because you mentioned not always will the object have an is_auth() method)? That way, DRF can avoid attribute errors?

Comment: @user2719875 not, because if request.user is None, python will not evaluate request.user.is_authenticated()